# Origem da palavra "canivete" vs "knife-let" em inglês

Tags: etimologia

Embora não exista, se adicionarmos o sufixo *-let* (que representa um tipo de diminutivo) à palavra *knife* em inglês, teremos a palavra *knifelet* que significaria algo como "faquinha", e que coincide de duas formas à palavra canivete, tanto no significado quanto numa pronúncia muito próxima (usando fonemas do português, claro).

Há alguma relação entre a palavra *knife* em inglês com a palavra *canivete* em português? Qual a origem da palavra *canivete*?

Comment: pocket knife ou penknife é canivete em  inglês.

Comment: Conheces a palavra «[naifa](https://priberam.pt/dlpo/naifa)»? Vem do inglês *knife*... :)

Comment: Não conhecia @ANeves, e agora surge outra dúvida: Algo a ver com `navalha` ? Soam similares, não ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Há sim senhor relação entre ***canivete*** e *knife*, mas sem o *-let*. Diz o dicionário Houaiss que *canivete* vem do francês antigo *canivet*, que significava ‘pequena faca’. E o [Centre National de Ressources Textuelle et Lexicalles (CNTRL)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/canif) explica que *canivet* vem de *canif*, que por sua vez vem provavelmente do frânquico **knif* (palavra não atestada, mas que se pensa ter existido) ou, menos provavelmente, do inglês antigo *cnif* (donde vem *knife*) ou nórdico antigo *knifr*. O [Etymoline (*knife*)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=knife) concorda que o francês antigo *canif* vem provavelmente de origem frânquica. Todas estas palavras têm uma origem comum no protogermânico.

Para completar, no inglês antigo o *i* era pronunciado mais ou menos como no português (só passou a ser pronunciado [ai] com a [great vowel shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift) dos séculos XIV-XVIII) e o [Etymoline (*kn-*)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=kn-&allowed_in_frame=0) explica ainda que o *k* de *kn-* (grafado *cn-* no inglês antigo) era pronunciado no inglês antigo e médio; portanto *cnif* soaria mais ou menos como um português ou brasileiro a leria, não muito diferente do francês antigo *canif*.

O [CTNRL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/canif) diz que *canivet* está atestado no século XII, e o Houaiss diz que estão atestados em português *canjuete* e *caniuete* (muitos textos antigos usam *u* no lugar de *v*) no século XIV e *canivete* no século XV. Eu só consegui encontrar uns *canivetes* do século XV, na [*Crónica dos Frades Menores*](https://archive.org/stream/crnicadaordemd02nune#page/212/mode/2up/search/canivete) (aqui edição de 1918, originalmente um manuscrito do século XV; negrito meu):

> E, como dissesse o *pater noster*, ante que comesse, vyo os Çeeos abertos e huum angeo de Deus, que deçemdia e trazia hũa pena d'ouro e huuns mantees e huum **canivete**, e emtrou em no refertoiro e primeiramente cortou ao que lia do peito ataa o enbigoo com o **canivete** e lavô-o com agoa e alimpô-o com o mantel e scpreveo em no [seu] coraçom com letras d'ouro estas palavras: *Johanes est nome[u] ejus*, que quer dizer, Johane he o seu nome.

Comment: knivelet não existe. ***Canivete em inglês se diz: pocket knife ou penknife***. Vale a pena dizer, en passant.

Comment: @Lambie isso é sabido, e para evitar esse mal entendido é extremamente a introdução da pergunta: "Embora não exista..."

Comment: @Luciano Pois é, se existe a palavra correspondente em termos de significado a canivete, porqué inventar bobagem? Eu acho que foi "inventado" por falta de conhecimento e sem sentido.

Comment: Então você não entendeu a pergunta, e nem a resposta, aliás excelente trabalho do Jacinto. @Lambie

Comment: @Luciano Qual é a origem de canivete em português e knife em inglês? Não estou criticando o santo do monte. Estou criticando a pessoa que fez a pergunta. Porqué que vocês não admitem que é bobagem inventar algo para compará-lo com outra coisa? Credo.

Comment: @lambie ninguém criou nada, é apenas uma suposição com coincidência fonética. Você realmente não entendeu a pergunta. Mas está perdoado.

Comment: Então antigamente *knight* soava a **[k-nigh-et](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A8yjNbcKkNY#t=88)**? Uau... ;) nunca pensei aprender filologia com Monty Python!

Comment: @ANeves :) Já se escreveu [*cniht* (Etymoline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=knight).Com mais o que diz em [*gh* na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gh_(digraph)#English), imagino que fosse como "knijt" com *j* à espanhola.